# Parenting with ctrl+p doesn't work in one specific file

Tags: rigging, parent

I'm learning how to animate in Blender, after many years animating in Maya, and I came across a weird problem the first time I tried to make a character hold a cellphone.

I found a tutorial that teaches how to rig an object so it can be animated with the character in pose mode. It was basically create a single bone armature and use the ctrl+p to make the object be parented to the bone. I followed the steps, but it didn't work.

I then created 2 other objects to verify if my method of parenting was incorrect, and it didn't work again.

I opened a new file an tried to parent 2 object with the same method and in this other file it worked. It just doesn't work in the file I need it to work.

When I try to parent any 2 objects in that specific file what I get is a dotted line between th 2 objecs, but both objects can be movd freely as if none of them weren't parented to the other.

What may have happened to this file that is preventing the parenting to work?

By the way, I'm using Blender 3.6

[image]

Comment: Dotted lines is relationship lines, meaning one is parent of the other. Now, depending what else you did to these objects, or your interaction mode, the parenting might not work as you expected. For exampe, did you parent the mesh object to the armature object or to the bone? You coming from Maya, I guess that's the biggest difference you will meet: joints are objects in maya, bones in Blender are elements of the Armature object. So if you parented the mesh object to the armature, it's normal for the bone to not affect the mesh object.

Comment: The detailed process I did was:

(in Object Mode)

SHIFT+A >> Armature - (It gives me a single bone)

Still on object mode I click on the object fist, then in that single bone, CTRL+P, 

click on "Keep transform without inverse"

and it works perfectly. Bot only in other files, not in the file I need it to work. 

In that file, not only parenting anythin with this bone is impossible, but also is impossible to parent ano other 2 objects.

And even in this file where it works, it only works in object mode, I need to be able to manipulate thsis object in pose mode.

Comment: The procedure you describe would parent your object to the armature object, not the bone element. In which case, it is normal if nothing happens in Pose mode. You should either use `Armature Deform With Automatic Weights` or `Bone Relative` if you have only one bone, or if you switched to pose mode and selected the bone you want to parent to.

Comment: What I tried to do now:

In a new file, not in the file I need it to work, I created a cube, then I created an armature , both with shift+a, then I clicked first on the  cube, it doesn't alowed me to switch to pose mode yet, so I, holding shift clicked on the armature, switched to pose mode, and in pose mode I pressed ctrl+ P. I the moved the bone in the pose mode and nohing happened to the cube. I stwitched to object mode and moving the armture te cube moved together.

Comment: Sorry, I Hadn't seen the whole answer with the screenshots and everyhing, now I saw and it worked in the test file, I'll rty in the real file to see if it happens therm since inthat file no kind of parenting is working, which is weird.

Comment: Oops sorry, i forgot to mention I was going to post an answer with the details x) if it still doesn't work, please upload your file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and share the link here so that we can check what's going on.

Comment: Your explanation is very good, but I still have some issues. The object I'm trying to parent to a bone is actually a combination of many parts. Maybe I need to do something to make all of tem one single thing or something like that, because now only a tiny part of it is following the bone, not th whole thing. I'll upload the file then. The 2 objects in there are linked objects, should I upload alll ofthem o only the blend file I'm working on? I still don't understand so well how these .blend files work yet.

Comment: Having multiple objects doesn't change the thing, just select all of them before the armature and it works the same. However, I don't think you can rig linked objects as is. You'll need to make a library override on it to be able to regain some control on it. I edited my answer for that.

Comment: I think it's similar to Maya's references if I'm not wrong? I don't think you can skin referenced objects to a rig. But you can reference the rig to which you want to skin objects on, or the whole finished rigged model.

Comment: Yeah,the only difference between maya's reference ad Blender's link is that i maya we dont need to tell the software to override, it just assumes.  I did it here, but it still only works in some parts, not everything. I think there is something wrong with this file because parenting in general doesn't work o it while still works in other files.  There must be something I need to clean up in this file, maybe some node, or some code.

Comment: This is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=oKsbQWY6" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/oKsbQWY6/)

Comment: Got the file, managed to parent without issues, just a bit of cleanup needed to get things working smoothly. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rig linked objects as is. You'll need to make a library override on it to be able to regain *some* control on it.
You can do that from the outliner > <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > library override > make > selected:

[image]

But you won't be able to edit vertex weights: it's linked data after all. But it will be enough if you don't need to adjust them. No problems with bone parenting though.

---

## Cleanup

Before doing anything in your file, let's cleanup a bit, lots of your mesh objects have multiple Armature Deform modifiers and even transform animation data which I am pretty sure isn't meant to be here.

### Selecting the objects

From the outliner, <kbd>RBM</kbd> the Cellular collection that contains your mesh object, click `Select Objects` to select them all, and finally <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> one of these objects to make it active.

### Clearing animation

To remove everything, you can use the F3 searchbar and look for the "Remove Animation" operator.

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to decide precisely which parts of animation to keep, you could do the following:

In the viewport sidebar, hover your mouse over the Location channels, press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to clear all these channels' keyframes or <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> > *Clear Keyframes* or Clear Single Keyframe to target a specific channel.
Repeat on any channel you like.

You may also want to apply the scale ("Freeze" scale in Maya), it might avoid transformation issues down the line. For that, <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*.

To propagate these changes from the active object to all the selection (not needed if you used the Remove Animation operator), press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Animation Data*.

### Clearing modifiers

In Properties Editor > Modifiers Tab, delete all modifiers you see.
To propagate to the selection, press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > Copy Modifiers

## Armature Parenting

Maya treats "joints" as objects. Blender's bones are elements inside the Armature object. Parenting anything to the armature object will not allow you to animate it with the bones in pose mode.

To do that, there's a few different way:

### Automatic Weights

Select the object to parent, then the armature object, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > `Armature Deform - With Automatic Weights`:

[image]

This will parent the mesh object to the armature object, but also add an `Armature Deform` modifier which will allow the bones to deform the mesh depending on the individual bones' weights:

[image]

Since you asked automatic weights, Blender created vertex groups for each bone of the armature and tried to automatically assign the nearest geometry.

This is the most common and most flexible way to rig anything.

### Bone parenting

Select the object to parent, then the armature object.
If you have multiple bones in your armature, press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to switch into Pose Mode, select the bone you want to parent to, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > `Bone` or `Bone Relative` (keeps the offset). If you have only one bone in the armature, you can already parent as above:

[image]

This will make a regular parent relationship, which you can also see in the object's property tab:

[image]

It's less common than weights outside very simple rigs, or proxy rigs.

### Bone Envelopes

Select the object to parent, then the armature object, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > `Armature Deform - With Envelope Weights`:

[image]

Parents to the armature, adds the Armature Deform modifier, but deforms according to the bone's envelope shape which you can enable here:

[image]